How can I change Wordpress Multisite "lang"
I spent many hours researching for this, but can't find the right answer.
I have a WordPress multisite with with three subfolders:

example.com/ lang="en-US"
example.com/uk lang="en-UK"
example.com/ie lang="en-IE"
example.com/ca lang="en-CA"

I would like to change the "lang" of the main domain to lang="en", because I want to add another subfolder for USA which will be:
example.com/us lang="en-US"
Thank you in advance!

Please edit your question to explain what you're doing to set the languages on the subfolders.
